# Cannot map html file with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot application with Intellij. It creates a sample web application with a controller and an empty html page.

But problem is this sample application returns "Whitelabel Error Page" when I go to "http://localhost:8080/info/aa". I think It cannot find info.html file. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is sample controller;

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/info")
public class InfoController {

    @RequestMapping("/aa")
    public String getServerInfo(Map<String, Object> model){

        model.put("message", "server info");
        return "info";

    }

}
```

My project directory;

[image]

**EDIT:** My html file info.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 2:** I update my html directory to templates/info.html

[image]

DemoApplication class;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**And application.properties file is empty.**

Comment: Please, post also the code from `DemoApplication` class

Comment: Also, what is the exception that you are getting? Spring should log the stacktrace if you get `Whitelabel Error Page` in your browser.

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I am getting "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"

Comment: When you start the application, can you see in the log the mapping for 'info/aa'? Should be something like this `Mapped "{[/info/aa]}" onto public java.lang.String your.package.InfoController. getServerInfo(java.util.Map<String, Object> model) `

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Yes there is a log "Mapped "{[/info/aa]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.InfoController.getServerInfo(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)"

Comment: @hellzone you are using jsp, which is smth diffrent afaik, if I am right you should put your info.html under ` src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` and it actually should be named `info.jsp`, example here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `info.html` is actually a template file then it obviously shouldn't be in a static content, it should be in a `templates` folder, as its not static.

Here is an example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Under `static` folder you have all static content, which wouldn't change when you serve it, for example, images, css, js scripts and so on.

Under `templates` folder you store templates from which spring + its template ending(for example thymeleaf) will generate actual html, using your `model`, which will be served to a client.

Also if you have a subfolder in templates like `templates/info/info.html` then you should return `info/info` as a template name from your controller, not just `info`.

However if you are using jsp then its something different, and you shouldn't use `template` folder, you should create `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` folders and put it there and you should name your template `info.jsp` then, instead of `info.html`

Example here: 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: I put info.html file into templates folder and I am still getting same error page

Comment: @hellzone what is your path to the file? if its `templates/info/info.html` then in controller you should retur `"info/info.html"` instead of `"info.html"`

Comment: Its templates/info.html and returning "info" from controller as above.

Comment: @hellzone sorry my mistake, should have returned `"info/info"` without `.html` if it still doesn't work, can you please update your question with your new structure

Comment: @hellzone I updated my answer regarding that you are using `jsp`

Comment: I acccepted your answer and its true for jsp files but my problem is Intellij didn't add thymelef framework for this sample project and It can't resolve views I think.

Comment: @hellzone when you are creating spring-boot application in idea there is a view where you choose parts of spring you need, however if you added it there and its still not in the dependencies, then it could be a bug

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put your `info.html` into `static/info` folder inside your resources, instead put it into `templates`.
The `@RequestMapping` on top of your `InfoController` class does not tell where to find the requested `html` files, it is just a mapping for your request.

If you want to have separates folder for different `html` pages you can have the `info` folder inside of your `templates` folder, but you still have to refer is in your controller as `info/info`:

```
@RequestMapping("/aa")
public String getServerInfo(Map<String, Object> model){

    model.put("message", "server info");
    return "info/info";

}
```

Comment: I put it into templates folder and I am still getting same error page.

Comment: @hellzone Could you update your project directory screenshot with the new structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSP (like I see you want) first of all move the html files to the folder:

```
/src/java/webapp/
```

and change the extension to .jsp. Then you will have your view file in:

```
/src/java/webapp/info/info.jsp
```

Secondly you have to add configuration for view resolving:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

And in the controller rember to return path of the file - you have configured head to .../templates and you have to return **info/info**:

```
@RequestMapping("/info")
public String info() {
    return "info/info";
}
```